# Trying to delete all records in android's sqlite db but no effect

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using rawQuery to delete all records from table:

```
final SQLiteDatabase dbWritable = this.getWritableDatabase();
dbWritable.rawQuery("DELETE FROM "+T5_NAME, null);
```

but this code has no effect. All of records are still there after execution. 
Why is that?

PS now i use dbWritable.delete(T5_NAME, null, null) - that works. But why rawQuery doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) returns [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) over the result set. So it's ment to be run with queries which return result set. And [delete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method that you are using uses some predefined values for constructing delete statements.

Comment: thought its "low level" manager for any SQL purpose including delete, drop etc...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29). It is meant for statements other than SELECT statements.